# Solr Query to get back data by date month & year

Tags: javascript, solr, export-to-excel

I have a requirement to get data back using solr by month & year, Eg: all date for a month of a given year like `"March 2016"`.

In my DB the data is stored like so `"2015-01-05T10:16:38Z"`

I was able to get data back using month+ year via WCF but currently we are switching from WCF to Solr for faster indexing.

Does anyone where know how to get this working? i tried the format `"2000-11"` mentioned in the docs but it doesn't work, can some tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a range query, something along the lines of

```
fq=date_field:[2015-01-01 TO 2015-02-01]
```

There is a also a lot of date math that you can do. Here is the link to the docs:
[Working With Dates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates)

Comment: Yes, i have looked at the docs and in there it says "2000-11 – The entire month of November, 2000." So I tried  "fq=date_field:2015-05" and still it doesnt work.

Comment: I get this error when i try it your way

`code: "msg": "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'pret_create_date:[2016-05-01  To 2016-06-01]': Encountered \" <RANGE_GOOP> \"2016-06-01 \"\" at line 1, column 33.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    \"]\" ...\r\n    \"}\" ...\r\n    ",
    "code": 400`

Comment: The 'To' inside the range query has to be capitalized. Try this: pret_create_date:[2016-05-01 TO 2016-06-01]

Comment: i get this error "msg": "Invalid Date String:'2016-05-01'"

Comment: Does this work?  pret_create_date:[2016-05-01T00:00:00Z TO 2016-06-01T00:00:00Z]

Comment: doesn't throw any error but doesn't get any data back too

Comment: Ok, confirm that you actually have data that matches.